# Display image in td on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, hover

Here is what I am trying to achieve (not sure if it's even possible):

Hover the mouse over a td, and in the bottom right corner of that td (perhaps overlapping the cell border), show a small image.

I'm okay with jQuery, so I can handle the hovering, but the CSS kills me. How do I position the image? Would I have the image in every cell, and only show it on hover? Or is there a better way?

I'm on IE7. I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid putting an image into every single td in the page you could also use a background image:

```
td{
  background-image: url('/yourImage.png');
  background-position: -2000px -2000px;
}

td:hover{
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

The reasoning for using the initial offset is that it makes sure that the image is pre-loaded with the page and so there's no lag during the first mouseover.

**Browser support issues**

I'm not sure how well supported the positioning directions are for different browsers and you may also want to check out this article to make sure that the :hover pseudo class works correctly for your target browsers. IE7+ will support the :hover pseudo class but they need the correct doctype (and a good prevailing wind)
http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

**Using jQuery instead**

If you don't want to use :hover you can stick to jquery to add and remove a class. The equivalent CSS for that would be:

```
td{
  background-image: url('/yourImage.png');
  background-position: -2000px -2000px;
}

td.hoverclass{
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

where ".hoverclass" is the classname that you add to the td during the mouseover period.

Comment: This is also a good way to do it, but to keep in mind that not all browsers (notably IE) support the `:hover` attribute on elements other than `<a>` tags.  If you use this method, I would go with the jQuery version as you have a better chance of users having JavaScript enabled than you do of them having the most up-to-date browser.

Comment: Jared, IE does actually support :hover above v7 as long as you have the correct doctype (updated in answer). That said, for safety I would probably also chose the jQuery version as you know what you're getting.

Comment: Is there any way to set this up so that the image can be a hyperlink?

Comment: @chrislegend Using this method, not really.  Technically, yes it's possible, but then you are making the code more complicated than it needs to be.  In that case, if you look at my original answer and instead of applying the style to #id-of-image, you would wrap the `<img>` with an `<a>` and then style the `<a>` the same as #id-of-image was.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this will show and hide images in a td.

```
td img
{
 display:none;
}

td:hover img
{
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do the positioning, what you want to use is absolute positioning.  The CSS would be:

```
#id-of-td {
    position: relative;
}

#id-of-image {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The HTML should be similar to:

```
<td id="id-of-td">
    <img id="id-of-image" src="path/to/image" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is good. Is there a way to push it even further into the bottom right corner?

Comment: That should be all the way in the right corner.  Check your padding and margins if it's not.  Also make sure that the `<img>` tag is a direct child of the `<td>` and not inside some other element in the `<td>`.

Comment: as far as I can see this only works in IE, I think it's because IE's wrong. You can't position table cells, so you can't Absolutely Position inside them? - [test example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/yvbrM/)

Comment: @clairsuzy, you may be right, I didn't actually test it.  However, using your test example, the result displays as it should in Chrome.  In the event that you cannot position cells, you could always put a container `<div>` inside the cell (which would cause the cell to wrap it) and then absolutely position inside of the `<div>`